# How to insert href link in this button tag

Tags: php, css

Hey i want to put this into href link in this button how to input that

> `\"/led=ON\"\"`

This is button code with animation

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-cons btn-animated from-top fa fa-arrow-up"><span>Open</span></button>
```

Comment: Type `href="led=ON"` into the tag? Won't do anything, but your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Also buttons don't have href's. Links do,

Comment: If you're planning to do it this way you're better off using a link instead of a button and styling it to look like a button by giving it a width/height, border, back color, etc...

Answer (score 0):

To give you a very bare-bones example of my comment above (formatting a link as a button), here is a decent place to start. Feel free to format it however you want of course.

HTML Hyperlink:

```
<a href="#" class="linkLikeButton">Example</a>
```

CSS Class:

```
.linkLikeButton {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

  .linkLikeButton:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
```

Comment: @MuhammadArianNasa np, if this solved your issue mark as an answer if you don't mind :)